# SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate:s3_pkt.c:1259:SSL alert number 42

Tags: ssl, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I've enabled SSL for a distributed database (cassandra), where each of the peers have the same keystore and trustore files. I've imported the Comodo signed certificate into the keystore, and also the intermediate and root certificates provided by Comodo. Into the truststore I've uploaded the root certificate and the intermediates. Below is the output I'm getting when I run a `openssl s_client`. I'm getting the below mentioned error:

> 139810559764296:error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3
>   alert bad certificate:s3_pkt.c:1259:SSL alert number 42
>   139810559764296:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake
>   failure:s23_lib.c:184:

At the end of the message however I get `"Verify return code: 0 (ok)"`.

The cluster seems fine and the peers are able to recognize each other though.

> openssl s_client -host example.xyz -port 10145
>
> CONNECTED(00000003)
>
> depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network,
>   CN = AddTrust External CA Root
>
> verify return:1 depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford,
>   O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
>
> verify return:1 depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford,
>   O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure
>   Server CA
>
> verify return:1 depth=0 C = US, postalCode = *****, ST = **, L =
>   *****, street = ****, O = ****, OU = dvrci1, OU = ******, OU = ******, CN = hostname
>
> verify return:1140115008423752:error:14094412:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate:s3_pkt.c:1259:SSL
>   alert number 42 140115008423752:error:140790E5:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:184: SSL
>   handshake has read 6648 bytes and written 354 bytes New, TLSv1/SSLv3,
>   Cipher is AES128-SHA Server public key is 2048 bit Secure
>   Renegotiation IS supported Compression: NONE Expansion: NONE
>   SSL-Session:
>       Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>       Cipher    : AES128-SHA
>       Session-ID: 57EBD44A5F04D45A44137682F375F1BFE2C45B27182927FC23F7255FC0B37226
>       Session-ID-ctx:
>       Master-Key:  A771BCAFB4DD8CC3D8C476F9DBA542998EC5CE926ADB4612C433668D515F03C38D519D6CE2434F52
>   4273320CF24476FC
>       Key-Arg   : None
>       Krb5 Principal: None
>       PSK identity: None
>       PSK identity hint: None
>       Start Time: 1475080428
>       Timeout   : 300 (sec)
>       Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: sorry, trying to edit it